# I'm completely new to electronics, can I make a wireless keyboard wired?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I lost the dongle to an old wireless keyboard, can I make it wired?[image: what I see]

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497229/without-the-use-of-any-software-what-would-be-the-cheapest-way-to-connect-my-br/497236#497236

Comment: Not easily, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner, "no".  Even an expert would have trouble converting that to USB or some other kind of wired.

You could maybe splice the charger cable and the receiver dongle together producing a semi-tethered wireless keyboard.

otherwise you need to replace the whole green circuit-board with one designed for USB operation.

Comment: OP should be able to use an open-source laptop keyboard USB controller project.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Comment: IMO an 'expert' would recognize this effort as a waste of time and instead just buy a wired keyboard ...